# nested transactions not supported When insert a record by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The error code like

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at roseindia.PersonDetail.main(PersonDetail.java:16)
```

This is my code

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Person person = new Person();
System.out.println("Inserting Record");
session.beginTransaction();
person.setId(1);
person.setName("Jeff");

session.save(person);
session.getTransaction().commit();

System.out.println("Done");
session.close();
```

I didn't begin transaction before commit the old one.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting transaction twice (at second line and sixth one).

That's why you have this error. With your configuration you cannot create transaction in transaction.